# Good way to store unique integers

Tags: java, collections, unique

**My Question Is:** What's a fast way to determine whether a number is contained in a `Collection` to know whether to add it to the collection and maintain uniqueness. I would rather not iterate through the list if I can help it.

I have a `List<Integer>` called `numberList`. I want it to store unique integers and never allow duplicates to be added. I would like to do something like this:

```
private void add(int number) {
  if (!numberList.contains(number)) {
    numberList.add(number);
  }
}
```

But obviously this wont work because `numberList` contains a list of `Integer` objects so regardless of the number each is a unique object.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the `contains(...)` method uses the object's `equals(...)` method to see if it is held by the collection or not, so your method above should prevent duplicates as well.

Comment: Huh, maybe something else is wrong with my code which is yielding the unexpected results then. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: if your code is like mine, then there's *always* something else wrong! Please come on back with more info if you need help finding it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One is to store the Integers in a `Set<Integer>` such as a `HashSet<Integer>`. Sets do not allow duplicates.

**Edit**
Also, the Collection's `contains(...)` method uses the object's equals(...) method to see if it is held by the collection or not, so your method above will prevent duplicates as well, if you need to use a List as your collection. Test this out yourself and you'll see it's so.

For instance:

```
  List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int[] myInts = {1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4};
  for (int i : myInts) {
     if (!numberList.contains(i)) {
        numberList.add(i);
      }
  }

  System.out.println(numberList);
```

will return: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Also, one possible problem with HashSets is that they're not ordered, so if ordering is important, you'll want to look at using one of the other varieties of ordered Sets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which implementation do you think would be faster? Would it be faster to let the `Set` deal with duplicates or to use `contains` on a List before adding?

Comment: @kentcdodds: I believe that the HashSet would be quicker since hashing is a very quick operation, but I can't say with 100% assurance since I've never studied big O for algorithms. But hang around, one of the computer scientists will answer this soon, no doubt.

Comment: of course using a HashSet is faster. One can also avoid the `if (!contains) add..` pattern, as HashSet.add does check this internally and returns true, if a new element has been added to the set.

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't the most compact form be a `BitSet`? It is efficient in terms of storage as it will expand indefinitely. It will also not use storage unnecessarily.

Are you working in a multi-threaded environment? If so there are other structures that may be better/more efficient.

Comment: You got me! It is a multi-threaded environment, which is why I'm doing this. I want to check whether one thread has already added the number.

Comment: In that case you are almost certainly looking for `ConcurrentHashMap`, perhaps wrapped in a set derived using [newSetFromMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) but you can always add `Boolean.TRUE` to the `Map` instead if you like.

Comment: BitSet is very efficient for small, dense sets of numbers. But `new BitSet().add(Integer.MAXVALUE);` already allocates 268MB. So it should be used carefully.

Comment: @Arne - Right, but so long as that element exists in the set that is all it will ever allocate. Of course, not useful for every use case but there are some where the fact that no further allocations will take place and the extremely low constant factor make this very attractive.